# How to get a reference to custom settings in webpart from a page within webpart?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I created a webpart, then I created a second .cs page that will render custom html.  It basically just a simple page to show an image.  However in the second .cs page, I need to access custom settings in the Web Part.  How can I access custom tool pane settings in the main web part when the link to the secondary page is clicked?

The second page is generated from VS 2010 and is in the layouts folder, looks like:

```
    public partial class GetFile : LayoutsPageBase
    {
```

I am thinking I have to inherit something from the web part in order to do this, but really not sure how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the Web part properties using the `SPLimitedWebPartManager` class by reading the web part collection and their properties on the page as shown below,

```
        var web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        var currentPageURL = "//URL of the page on which the Web part is present";
        var page = web.GetFile(currentPageURL);
        using (SPLimitedWebPartManager webPartManager = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared))
        {
            try
            {
                var webPartList = from System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart webPart in webPartManager.WebParts select webPart;

                foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart webPart in webPartList.ToList())
                {
                    if (webPart.Title.ToLower() == "//Name of the web part for which you want to read the properties")
                    {
                        PropertyInfo[] wptProperties = webPart.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                        foreach (PropertyInfo property in wptProperties)
                        {
                            if (property.Name == "//Name of the web property which you want to get")
                            {
                                // Following code updates the web part property, you can also read it
                                property.SetValue(webPart, "value to be set", null);
                                webPartManager.SaveChanges(webPart);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Response.Redirect(currentPageURL);
            }
            finally
            {
                webPartManager.Web.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for  posting your answer.  This works perfectly as is.  Just one question, since the url and title of the webpart can change.  Is the best method is to pass along the webpart url and the title when calling the page?  or is there another best method?  I can see that having to put in the url and title can be a bit of a problem if it changes.

Comment: It seems that you are writing code in second.cs file, in this case if your webpart resides on the second.aspx file i.e,, on the same page for which you have created the "SPLimitedWebPartManager" instance then you dont need to use the URL to create the Page object. instead you can use the current page instance. and instead of web part title you can use web part type which will never change.